# How to do unsubscribe from SMS via Email and vice versa

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, sms, unsubscribe

Is it possible to unsubscribe from the email and have it removed from the SMS automatically, and vice versa?

Thank you all

Comment: Please provide more details about the problem you are trying to solve, because it’s not clear what you’re asking.

Comment: I want that when a customer doing unsubscribe from the subscribers list via email, then he will be automatically removed from the SMS subscribers too.

Comment: How does the customer unsubscribe, using the ootb unsub link? Are you using publication lists?

Comment: We have a custom cloudpage that updates the status in all subscribers using LogUnsubEvent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are a few ways you can interact with a Subscription of a Mobile
> Contact for SMS Messaging:
>
> - Manually create a Subscription in the UI
> - Import a Contact into MobileConnect
> - Mobile Opt In Message Template
> - Use the REST API to create a Contact and Subscription
> - Journey Builder SMS Activity

Specifically, to update to Opted Out Status you have the following options:

- The UI manually
- Import Definition
- Mobile Keyword (STOP/Custom STOP keyword)
- REST API

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000381673&language=en_US

So in your case, since you have to do it programmatically from a CloudPage, you have two options, one that would be real-time and another that would have to run in batches.

**Option 1, real-time:**

Use the REST API, the recommended Route is the [QueueMO](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postQueueMO.htm) route, but you can also use the [messageContact](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postMessageContactSend.htm) route as well. You would need to write a script to call the API to unsubscribe from specific keywords and add that script to your CloudPage where you already have the LogUnsubEvent script.

**Option 2, batch processing:**

Log all unsubscribes in in a Data Extension and set up an automation in Automation Studio to use an [Import Definition](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sf.mc_moc_import_mobile_contacts.htm&language=en_US) to update a Subscription from Opted In to Opted Out.

Comment: Thank you very much! We appreciate it, you helped us a lot!